# dotted line not showing up in view

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I'm trying to create this:

[image]

I set it up as follows:

layout.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/divder1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/receipt_top"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_cutout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_left_cutout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_cutout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_right_cutout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout        
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right_cutout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left_cutout"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_dotted_line_divider"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ic_dotted_line_divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/red"
        android:dashWidth="20dp"
        android:dashGap="15dp"
        android:width="10.5dp"/>
</shape>
```

and it ends up looking like this for some reason, my half circles show up but the line does not:

[image]

How do I get the dotted line to show up?

Also I tried doing this previously in a layer-list instead of a constraint layout but that didn't work because the width of the view could change but the heigh won't so that distorted the circles so this seems like the best route to take.

Comment: "How do I get the dotted line to show up?" -- have you tried giving the divider a height? Right now, your drawable does not specify a height, and your `ImageView` says the height is `wrap_content`.

Comment: @CommonsWare is right, you need to set a specific size to your height, try `android:layout_height="1dp"`

Comment: Also you can use a regular View with `background` rather than ImageView with a src for such a simple thing such as a divider

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all I wouldn't add the nested constraint layout and direclty place the imageView.

Probably you are missing the following properties in your middle view to specify it to fill the middle space. If anything sometimes using the editor also helps.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: it's in a constraint layout so I don't think I need a weight. It's constrained to the end of the left half circle and the start of the right half circle. I also first tried it without the nested constraint layout.

Comment: It is still relevant in the constraint layouts to specify that it should occupy the space. Views must have width and height. You specify left and right constraint but android is still dumb to understand how width should behave.

Comment: Oh I noticed the issue with the height of @CommonsWare either at the view or shape, so that must be placed as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your dashed line has no height. Neither the `ic_dotted_line_divider` drawable nor the `ImageView` that uses it declares a specific height. While the `ImageView` has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, the content is the drawable, and the drawable has no height.

So, whether in the drawable or in the `ImageView`, you will need to specify a  height, representing how thick the dashed line should be.